# How to get list of users who's birthday is today in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having the list of documents with date of birth in mongo collection.  We are having the front end where user can add the complex conditions on the data to get the result like

```
(user.dob isToday AND user.score > 1000) OR (user.dob isTomorrow AND user.score > 2000)
```

Other than date type, I am able to convert the above conditions to corresponding mongo query like `{"score" : { $gt: 1000}}`.

In case of birthday condition, we have to query the DB with day of the month and month of the year which is supported in mongo only by using aggregate which will not help for my above use case.

Anyone have suggestions? Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For MongoDB 3.6 and greater, to get the list of all users who have a birthday today, use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator which allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language:

```
db.users.find({
   "$expr": { 
       "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$dob" }, { "$dayOfMonth": new Date() } ] },
            { "$eq": [ { "$month"     : "$dob" }, { "$month"     : new Date() } ] }
       ]
    }
});
```

---

For other MongoDB versions, you need to run an aggregate operation that uses a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline to filter the documents with the help of **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator to do the redaction. Consider executing the following pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                "$and": [
                    { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$dob" }, { "$dayOfMonth": new Date() } ] },
                    { "$eq": [ { "$month"     : "$dob" }, { "$month"     : new Date() } ] }
                ]
            ],
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
]);
```

---

The **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expression above

```
"$cond": [
    "$and": [
        { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$dob" }, { "$dayOfMonth": new Date() } ] },
        { "$eq": [ { "$month"     : "$dob" }, { "$month"     : new Date() } ] }
    ]
],
```

essentially represents the conditional statement

```
if (dob.getDate() === day && dob.getMonth === month) {
    "$$KEEP" // keep the document in the pipeline
} else {
    "$$PRUNE" // prune/discard the document from the output
}
```

and the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline will return all documents that match the condition with the **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** (a system variable returned by **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** based on the **[`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)** and **[`$dayOfMonth`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#exp._S_dayOfMonth)** [date operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators)) and discards documents otherwise with **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)**.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The above solution will fetch only users who born on that particular year right. for example: 06-Jan-2016.  But I want all the users who's birthday falls under 6th of January to send the birthday wishes.

Comment: Had misunderstood your question back then but now I think the above edit will address that, please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregation framework with the `$dayOfYear` operator. I have assumed that the birth day is stored in the field `birthday` and that there is a field called `name`:

```
db.data.aggregate(
[
        {
                "$project" : {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : 1,
                        "birthday" : 1,
                        "score" : 1,
                        "todayDayOfYear" : {
                                "$dayOfYear" : new Date()
                        },
                        "birthDayOfYear" : {
                                "$dayOfYear" : "$birthday"
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "$project" : {
                        "name" : 1,
                        "birthday" : 1,
                        "score" : 1,
                        "isBirthDay" : {
                                "$eq" : [
                                        "$todayDayOfYear",
                                        "$birthDayOfYear"
                                ]
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "$match" : {
                        "isBirthDay" : true,
                        "score" : { $gt: 100}
                }
        }
]
)
```

Comment: this doesn't work in about 20% of cases since we have a thing called "leap years" ...

Answer (score 1):

[Nice solution, taken from here](https://github.com/vinicius0026/mongodb-birthday-query/blob/master/index.js)

```
const User = require('user');
const day = (new Date()).getDate();
const month = (new Date()).getMonth();

const users = await User.find({
    $where:`return this.birthday.getDate() === ${day} && this.birthday.getMonth() === ${month}`
}).exec();
```

Comment: Upvoted because is very clean, but the $where operator is not always allowed (especially in some well-known services offered by Mongodb).