# Select all users who have birthday in current month

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I just started learning NodeJs+MongoDB(Mongoose).
Have a problem with query.

I need to **select all users, who have birthday in current month**.

---

**Users Schema:**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    photo: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

**Example of collection (users) document:**

```
{ 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b26ab4490e29ab5bdc17c"), 
    "birthday" : ISODate("1982-08-17T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "email" : "test@gmail.com", 
    "firstName" : "John", 
    "lastName" : "Smith", 
    "password" : "$2a$10$/NvuIGgAYbFIFMMFW1RbBuRGvIFa2bOUQGMrCPRWV7BJtrU71PF6W", 
    "phone" : "1234567890", 
    "photo" : "photo-1486565456205.jpg", 
    "updated" : ISODate("2017-02-08T14:09:47.215+0000")
}
```

Comment: duplicate. Check out this question: [Answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614042/how-to-get-list-of-users-whos-birthday-is-today-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of all users who have birthday in current month, you need to run an aggregate operation that uses a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline to filter the documents with the help of **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator to do the redaction. Consider executing the following pipeline:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$month": "$birthday" },
                        { "$month": new Date() }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);
});
```

---

The **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expression above

```
"$cond": [
    {
        "$eq": [
            { "$month": "$birthday" },
            { "$month": new Date() }
        ]
    }
],
```

essentially represents the conditional statement

```
if (birthday.getMonth() === (new Date()).getMonth()) {
    "$$KEEP" // keep the document in the pipeline
} else {
    "$$PRUNE" // prune/discard the document from the output
}
```

and the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline will return all documents match the condition with the **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable returned by **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** based on the **[`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)** [date operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) and discards documents otherwise with **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have input dates i.e. fromDate and toDate, the the simple query is:

```
db.collection.find({"birthday":{$gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate}});
```

Comment: This will never work because you are filtering on a single year only.