# Catch users who have a birthday today with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a scheme in mongodb where the birth field saves birth dates in this format: 2001-01-02T12:00:00.000+00:00

How can I make a query that takes today's birthdays?

I tryed this code

```
const day = moment();

return await Schema.find({
              birth: {
                $gte: day.clone().startOf("day"),
                $lte: day.clone().endOf("day"),
              },
            })
```

but it doesn't work because the variable "day" has year 2020. It would only catch if someone was born today.

Comment: so you'll need to find where day and month are equal to todays day and month .... also, don't forget the people whose dob is 29/2 ... :p - maybe [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) will help you (look to the bottom of the page) ... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ for general documentation on aggregation pipeline operators

Comment: oh, look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614042/how-to-get-list-of-users-whos-birthday-is-today-in-mongodb

Comment: @JaromandaX works with aggregate. thanks. The $where operator is not allowed in new versions